# Will Xamarin Insights Expiration crash existing apps?

Tags: xamarin.forms, components

Recently I got an email from xamarin team that Xamarin Insights is retiring on 30th April, 2018. I am a bit worried as I already have few of the apps where I have implemented it. So my core question here is, will it cause my xamarin.forms mobile apps to crash if I do not replace it with AppCenter?

Answer (score 0):

You should have received a email like this:

Hi,

On April 30th, 2018, Xamarin Insights will be fully retired – you will no longer be able to collect or view any data in Xamarin Insights.

To ensure continuity, you need to do the following before April 30th:

1. Sign up for Visual Studio App Center, the next generation of Xamarin Insights.
   •   App Center is the future of Microsoft’s mobile app analytics, crash, and errors services going forward. These services are completely free.
2. Remove the Xamarin Insights SDK from your apps and integrate the App Center SDK. 
   •   **While the presence of the Xamarin Insights SDK will not prevent the apps from working for several months after retirement, you must remove the Xamarin Insights SDK**. We encourage you to integrate the App Center SDK to ensure continuity. Learn more.
   •   Please note, any logs received from the Xamarin Insights SDK after April 30th will be disregarded. 
   If you have any questions, please contact us immediately at insights@xamarin.com. We are here to help you ensure a smooth transition.

The Visual Studio App Center Team